# Observable on error call a second observable

Tags: javascript, observable

I want to call a second observable when the first observable get error 400.

```
this.service.runTest(resource)
  .subscribe(
    response => console.log(response),
    err => {
      this.service.runTest2(resource)
        .subscribe(
          response => {
            setTimeout(()=>{this.resultDisplay = response}, 4000);

          },
          err => console.log(err)
        )
    }
  );
```

Comment: I'm assuming this is JavaScript. If not (e.g. it's a certain library), please add a relevant tag to your question.

Comment: what kind of errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the catch operator to catch the error and react accordingly:

```
this.service.runTest(resource)
  .catch(err => 
      (err.status === 400) 
          ? this.service.runTest2(resource).delay(4000)
          : Observable.throw(err))
  .subscribe(
    response => console.log(response),
    err => err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: When I watch all the observable videos they say you are never supposed to nest observables.  Then say use a switchmap or something but I could not figure out how to call the second operator on a specific error.

Comment: Catch is the way to go for that use case. The videos are right, never nest subscriptions.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks so much!7